# jQuery smooth scroll positioning doesn't work

Tags: jquery, position, smooth-scrolling

I want to use a smooth scroll for my nav-links, but I am having a fixed nav, so I have to change the landing position a little bit.
Now I found the answer in this forum and it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-100
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

The "top-100" should work, but it just doesn't...
Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `console.log($target.offset().top-100);` in your console?

Comment: have you tried to wrap in brackets? e.g. `($target.offset().top)-100` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`partseInt`** to always use the **`int`** value in browsers.

```
'scrollTop':  parseInt($target.offset().top,10);
```

> **parseInt()** function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.

#### Syntax

```
parseInt(string, radix);
```

- **string** : The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to one.
- **radix** :  An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix of the above mentioned string.

---

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
    
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop':  parseInt($target.offset().top,10)
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Am I getting something wrong or isn't the second parameter of `parseInt` the numeral-system to be used defined be its numerical value ?

Comment: now it makes more sense ;-) .propably you can add the `-100` in your answer

Comment: There shouldn't be a semicon after parseInt ;)

Comment: Yeah, I removed semicolon :)