# jQuery smooth scrolling anchor navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I have a list based navigation at the top of my site, it's a one page site so the a hrefs are anchors to sections on the page. I've used this code: [jQuery smooth scroll positioning doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969019/jquery-smooth-scroll-positioning-doesnt-work)

Navigation:

```
<nav>
   <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="navigation"><a class="scroll" href="#about-me">about me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation"><a class="scroll" href="#my-skills" >my skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation"><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation"><a class="scroll" href="#contact">contact</a>
      </li>    
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Section/div:

```
<section id="contact"> <!---->
    <div class="panel" id="contact">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>
</section> <!---->
```

Javascript used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop':  parseInt($target.offset().top,10);
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The anchor works and it jumps to the section, but with no scrolling?

Comment: Consider using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `;` after `'scrollTop':  parseInt($target.offset().top,10)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few problems in your code:

> - **You haven't closed your `li`s properly**
> - **You have same `id`s for `section` and `div` which is invalid**

```
<section id="contact"> <!---->
    <div class="panel" id="contact">
```

So correcting the above mistakes I would like to add one more change in your **JS** which is:

> - **No need to add `parseInt` to `scrollTop`. You can directly go with the `offset().top`**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xya6gs93/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top //no need of parseInt here
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for pointing out the errors too!

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Comment: @Marinpietri Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        var scroll;

        if($(window).scrollTop()==0){
            scroll =  ($target.offset().top) - 160
        }else{
            scroll =  ($target.offset().top) - 60
        }
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': scroll
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            //window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That works perfectly! however my nav is set to height:10vh; to make sure the nav doesnt go over the the h2  title i've given it padding-top:10vh; when scrolling back up it scrolls to so the nav is at the top of the div meaning I get an unwanted 10vh gap, how can I resolve that?